# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40712

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

```
Future<User> registerUser(String username, String firstname, String lastname, String password, String email) 
      async {
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\nHello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        final response = await client
            .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/register', // the error exists here
            // headers: "", 
            body: jsonEncode({
              "emailaddress": email,
              "username": username,
              "password": password,
              "first_name": firstname,
              "last_name": lastname
            })
          );
```

I've tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to my manifest and changing the proxy on my emulator. Thanks

Comment: are you sure this address http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/register exists??

Comment: change 127.0.0.1:5000 with your pc actual IP adress. The 127.0.0.1 is pointing to your device. Even if in an emulator.

Comment: I've changed the IP,  but it shows the same error with my IP now.

Comment: would I need to change it to my IP on all instances?

Comment: just fixed it. You have to use 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1, as the latter is the computer's loopback interface and the former to host that interface

Comment: thanks that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a localhost loopback address. You'd need to use your machine's actual IP address to establish the connection.